# How to make this texture more realistic

Tags: texturing

I have this texture of concrete, but I'd like to make it more realistic. if it could have some dimples or some of the texture to seem its popping out, rough surface.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Plenty of free texture files online with associated displacement, roughness and normal files. There's a quick tutorial on using ones from Polyhaven.com [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYDo9Xh9g18) but most folks will probably use the [Node wrangler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iP3_WOl4aco) addon to import the materials directly into the shader in Blender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the very simplest level, you could convert your image to Greyscale, and use that as the basis for a Bump map (I softened it a bit with white as well to make it less "intense"):

[image: Bump]

The Bump Node will see dark areas as low and light areas as high, which works well for the scratches, but the dark areas around the edge of the image will be "lower" than the rest as well - this means that you can try and use the image to get some *roughness* values as well, but it may look a bit strange near the edges:

[image: Rough]

I disconnected the image color from the above image to try and lessen the impact - with the BaseColor connected, the effects are very noticeable (may be desired or not). Here it is with the image:

[image: Rough2]

Comment: Wow awesome! Thanks.